# Состояние триггера в zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Где хранится состояние триггера zabbix? То есть информация о том, работает он или нет. Думал, что поле `status` в БД отвечает за состояние узла сети, но как оказалось - нет. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать.

Документация говорит, что параметр `active` метода `trigger.get` возвращает все активные триггеры. Но у меня в виде массива возвращается информация обо всех триггерах, и нет такого элемента, который бы отвечал за их состояния.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT groups.name,
       hosts.hostid,
       hosts.host,
       triggers.description,
       triggers.comments,
       triggers.triggerid,
       triggers.priority
FROM triggers
INNER JOIN functions ON triggers.triggerid=functions.triggerid
INNER JOIN items ON items.itemid=functions.itemid
INNER JOIN hosts ON hosts.hostid=items.hostid
INNER JOIN hosts_groups ON hosts_groups.hostid=hosts.hostid
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.groupid=hosts_groups.groupid
WHERE hosts.status = 0
  AND items.status = 0
  AND triggers.status = 0
  AND triggers.value=1;
```